# How to use counter in for loop as input in bash file

Tags: bash, for-loop, input

I want to run a c code several time. In the c code, a varibale (`n` ) reads a value from command line. I want to write a bash file to do it for me. But I do not know how to read a value inside a loop in a bash file. 
the bash file is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXE=exc3_1
RES=$EXE.d
for i in 2 4 8 16
do  
  COMMAND="mpirun -n $i $EXE >> $RES"
  echo $COMMAND
  eval $COMMAND 
done

gnuplot << EOF
set datafile separator " "
set xlabel "Num of procs"
set ylabel "time of operation"
set title "weak scaling of trapezoidal rule"
plot $RES
EOF
```

and after command `eval $COMMAND` I should read value for `n`.

"EDITED"
and the value `n` should be used for the input argument in a c code as follows:

```
scanf("%d", &N);
```

I mean in every iteration in bash file, N should be read from command line and use as input for

```
scanf("%d", &N);
```

in a c code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read something from an external command, you can go two ways: 1: read directly the output of the command; and 2: redirect the output of the command to some well-known place, and read thereafter from there.

> COMMAND="mpirun -n $i $EXE >> $RES"
>     echo $COMMAND

It seems that you want to read some output from "mpirun", and you chose to redirect its output. In your code, the output from mpirun will be written (warning: **appended**) into a file named `exc3_1.d`. Probably you want to issue something like:

```
COMMAND="mpirun .... > ..."
eval $COMMAND              # execute the command
read yourvar < exc3_1.d    # read from where mpirun wrote to
```

BUT, I think that instead of redirecting away the output of mpirun, it would be best to read directly from it:

```
yourvar=$($COMMAND)
```

The above line executes what is specified in parentheses, takes the output, and stores in the variable named "yourvar".

[EDIT after comment]
I think the better option is to run your command as shown above, especially if you use multitasking. But I have no idea of what you are using mpirun for...
I say this because there are many ways, but all of them cope with "standard output", a mechanism you should understand before going on.

For the second part, deploy the content passing it to a C program, it's another matter - probably another question on this site can help. Again, there are two ways, via scanf():

```
echo $myvalue | $mycommand   # pass to standard input
```

(the program launched by $mycommand reads via scanf()), or:

```
eval "$mycommand $myvalue"
```

(suitable to pass myvalue as a parameter).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added more details to make the question more clear. As I added I want the code in each iteration of the bash file read a value for an argument, and use it as input for `scanf("%d", &N);` in a c code.

Comment: @Pejvak I Updated my answer, but you should experiment a bit.

Answer (score 0):

to use a command line input as input for a file, pipe `|` operator can be used, e.g.

```
read n
echo $n | eval $COMMAND
```

so the bash file should modified as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXE=exc3_1
RES=$EXE.d
for i in 2 4 8 16
do  
  COMMAND="mpirun -n $i $EXE >> $RES"
   echo $COMMAND
   read n
   echo $n | eval $COMMAND 
done

gnuplot << EOF
set datafile separator " "
set xlabel "Num of procs"
set ylabel "time of operation"
set title "weak scaling of trapezoidal rule"
plot $RES
EOF
```